copying DD to a folder and converting to qcow2
I am trying to copy disk image (block files) with resepct to KVM images and convert it to Qcow2 format in a single command,Can we copy copy dd to a folder and convert it to qcow2 in single command.

What did you try so far?

"block files" and "images" suggests more than one "source" file - which kind of sounds odd. Can you elaborate exactly what the "source" is - sounds a bit like you want to convert an existing VM's "disk image" to qcow2 ..
